# Appending JS array to a variable and displaying it?

Tags: javascript

Im trying to make a weird online program but im having trouble.

Here is my code:

```
        function name() {
        var titles = ["titles", "titles", "titles", "titles", "titles", "titles"];
        var randFor = Math.random();
        randFor = 7 * randFor;
        randFor = Math.floor(randFor);

        var finished = [];
        var arraySpot = 0;
        var newVal;
        var newValSpot = 0;
        newVal = finished[newValSpot];
        for (i = 0; i < randFor; i++) { 
            var randArray = Math.random();
            randArray = 7 * randArray;
            randArray = Math.floor(randArray);

            finished.push[arraySpot] = titles[randArray];

            arraySpot++;
            newValSpot++;
            newVal = " " + finished[newValSpot];
        }

        document.getElementById("gen").innerHTML =newVal;

    }
```

Basically, what im trying to do is take an array of words, and convert it to a variable and display it in this tag:

```
<div id="gen"></div>
```

But every time it gives me "undefined" with a space in front of it?

Any help is appreciated, sorry for being such a noob in JS.

*UPDATE*
I have revised the code, i no longer get "undefined" but now i get nothing?

```
        function name() {
        var titles = ["titles", "titles", "titles", "titles", "titles", "titles"];
        var randFor = Math.random();
        randFor = 7 * randFor;
        randFor = Math.floor(randFor);

        var newVal;
        newVal = title[0];
        for (i = 0; i < randFor; i++) { 
            var randArray = Math.random();
            randArray = 7 * randArray;
            randArray = Math.floor(randArray);

            newVal = " " + titles[randArray];
        }

        document.getElementById("gen").innerHTML = newVal;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope this is useful

- `newVal = finished[newValSpot];` At this time, `finished` is still empty array, so you got an `undefined` value.
- `finished.push[arraySpot] = titles[randArray];` Please check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) for push method.
- `newVal = " " + titles[randArray];` This will assign `newVal` a new value, I guess you want to do this. `newVal = " " + titles[randArray];`

**Update**

- `var titles = ["titles", "titles", "titles", "titles", "titles", "titles"];` The `titles` length is 6, not 7, you should add one more "titles" into `titles`.
- `newVal = " " + titles[randArray];` The same issue, I think you want to do this. `newVal = newVal + " " + titles[randArray];`

```js
function name() {
  // Add one more "titles" in this array.
  var titles = ["titles", "titles", "titles", "titles", "titles", "titles", "titles"];
  var randFor = Math.random();
  randFor = 7 * randFor;
  randFor = Math.floor(randFor);

  var newVal;
  newVal = titles[0];
  for (i = 0; i < randFor; i++) {
    var randArray = Math.random();
    randArray = 7 * randArray;
    randArray = Math.floor(randArray);

    newVal = newVal + " " + titles[randArray];
  }

  document.getElementById("gen").innerHTML = newVal;

}

name();
```

```html
<div id="gen"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this fixed everything and now i know what to do in the future, im new to JS so this is a ton of help! Thanks!